# Required services that are not installed "jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.mail.GmailSES",

Tags: java, smtp, wildfly, mail-server

```
"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EmployeeAttendenceAPI.war\component.CommonMailTemplateWebService.START",
"jboss.deployment.unit.\"EmployeeAttendenceAPI.war\component.ShiftAutomationNewMail.START",      "jboss.deployment.unit.\"EmployeeAttendenceAPI.war\".component.ShiftAutomationNewMail.WeldInstantiator",etc
```

I tried to generate the war in my java application, unable to do, my wild fly server showing this error ,

checked  mail server smtp-its configured well in my standalone.bat, also added java mail jar file,
the same mail configuration working fine in another project, why here it showing error

Comment: Your JNDI configuration to get your mail session looks wrong. Paste the mail subsystem configuration to see where the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"GmailSES"-is the  Resource(lookup) name    like this "**@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/mail/GmailSES")*"" in my Backend java code,
this name missed in my Data Source list in a standalone.xml..after added it the error went. GmailSES** is a custom name ,So whenever you face the *Required services that are not installed* try to check the **name**...and the line where it is showing ;);):(